# Null pointer access warning on enum type

Tags: java, enums

My MainActivity code is

```
private void updateConnectionState()
      {
              Device localDevice = this.Controller.getConnectedDevice();
              if (localDevice == null)

              updateModelSpinner(localDevice.getType());    //warning at this line          
              str2 = localDevice.getHostName();
              if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str2))

            }




private void updateSpinner(Device.Type paramType)
      {
        boolean bool = Device.Type.UNKNOWN.equals(paramType);
        int i = 0;
        if (!bool)
          i = 1 + paramTvType.ordinal();
        this.ModelSpinner.setSelection(i);
      }

private void ModelSpinner(Device.Type paramType)
      {
        boolean bool = Device.Type.UNKNOWN.equals(paramType);
        int i = 0;
        if (!bool)
          i = 1 + paramType.ordinal();
        this.ModelSpinner.setSelection(i);
      }
```

My enum class is

```
public class Device {

    private Type type = Type.A_LOGIC;   

    public static Type getTypeForId(int paramInt)
      {
        switch (paramInt)
        {
        default:
          return Type.A_LOGIC;      
        case 0:
          return TvType.B_LOGIC;
        case 1:
          return TvType.A_LOGIC;
        case 2:
          return TvType.D_LOGIC;
        case 3:
          return TvType.E_LOGIC;
        case 4:
        }
        return TvType.F_LOGIC;          
      }

  public void setType(Type paramType)
      {
        this.Type = paramType;
      }

     public enum Type
     {       
         A_LOGIC("A_LOGIC"),                
         B_LOGIC ("B_LOGIC" ),      
         C_LOGIC ("C_LOGIC"), 
         D_LOGIC("D_LOGIC"),
         E_LOGIC ("E_LOGIC"),
        UNKNOWN("UNKNOWN");

        private String object;

        TvType(String localobj)
        {
            this.object; = localobj;
        }       
        public String getLetter()
        {
          return this.object;;
        }       
     }

 public Type getType()
      {
        return this.type;
      }
```

and in my main activity inside the method am calling type as

`updateSpinner(localDevice.getType());`

but here it is showing the warning as

```
Null pointer access: The variable localTVDevice can only be null at this location
```

and throwing an null point error at that line.
Am new to the concept of enum so please tell me why it is throwing this error.I referred stack overflow but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You should share your updateSpinner method.

Comment: And all your calling code. Your posted code and your error message refer to different variable names, and we need to see what you actually have written.

Comment: You might want to use an enum with a numeric field and use `name()` where you use `object`. Also check your switch `case 1` there might be a typo here (`C_LOGIC`)

Comment: Umm show the code where you call the method that throws the error. The warning says nothing about the enum. This probably has nothing to do with the Device class. Rather, you have declared an object variable for a Device but haven't instantiated anything in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this code

```
if (localDevice == null)
    updateModelSpinner(localDevice.getType());
```

If localDevice is null,
  Then call updateModelSpinner(null.getType())

You probably want this code:

```
if (localDevice != null)
    updateModelSpinner(localDevice.getType());
```

You'll have to decide what should happen when localDevice is null..

Comment: let me try this and let u know. Thanks for ur answer

Comment: @AndroidOptimist This is essentially the same as RC's answer - which you said didn't help for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Rolf i resolved this issue. This is silly issue which i didn't noticed.

Answer (score 2):

From your code:

```
Device localDevice = this.Controller.getConnectedDevice();
if (localDevice == null)

updateModelSpinner(localDevice.getType());
```

as the if has no `{}`, this code is similar to:

```
Device localDevice = this.Controller.getConnectedDevice();
if (localDevice == null) {
    updateModelSpinner(localDevice.getType());
}
```

hence the warning

**FIX:**

```
Device localDevice = this.Controller.getConnectedDevice();
if (localDevice != null) {
    updateModelSpinner(localDevice.getType());
    // more code using localDevice
}
```

Comment: i tried this but still facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

This compiler warning indicates that a variable (in this case **localTVDevice** ) is not assigned a value and calling  a method through this variable will no doubt produce **NullPointerException** at runtime.

And also one thing I see in your code? You can compare enum values directly with '==' instead of equals as you do in the this line:

```
boolean bool = Device.Type.UNKNOWN.equals(paramType);

boolean bool = paramType == Device.Type.UNKNOWN;
```